# Which java ORM is suitable for android OS and support lazy list?

Tags: android, sqlite, orm

I wanna choose a best and suitable ORM library for android to use in my app. I know about GreenADO and ORMLite but not a lot.

Could you compare between them and mention advantages/disadvantages of them? 
And also tell which one support lazy list?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Green DAO vs ORM lite vs Active Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680954/green-dao-vs-orm-lite-vs-active-android)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use GreenDAO, because of its rapidity ([see performance](http://greendao-orm.com/features/)). It's easy to use and you can do very easily lazyLoading. ORMLite has a bigger community I think but seems slower.

About lazy-loading, in ORMLite you have to use DAO.iterator(Query) which returns an iterator, so you need a custom adapter. With greendao, you can use Query.lazyList(), which returns a list.

I would suggest you to go to GreenDAO.